# How to convert filtered query with Multi_Match to filtered query with Common Terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES 2.0. I have the following filtered query with `multi_match`:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query": { 
                "multi_match" : {
                    "query" : "sleep",
                    "fields" : ["title.*^10","introduction.*"],
                    "cutoff_frequency" : 0.001,
                    "operator" : "or",
                    "analyzer" : "standard"
                }
        },
        "filter" : {
            ...
        }
}
```

Because of stop words issue, I would like to replace the Multi_Match with Common Terms explained here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/stop-stopping-stop-words-a-look-at-common-terms-query

How can I just replace the above `multi_match` with Common Terms? I cannot figure out how to handle the search on multiple fields based on Common Terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying the `cutoff_frequency` in your `multi_match` query, you're already using common terms, as mentioned in the blog article you linked to:

> "Common Terms has also been incorporated into the Match query and can
>   be enabled by setting `cutoff_frequency` to a value like 0.001"

The documentation for `match` and `multi_match` on [`cutoff_frequency`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-cutoff) also mention this fact.

Comment: No prob, always happy to help!