# How to search multiple fields using * by using Common Terms

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```
"mappings": {

    "mydoctype": {
        ....        
        "properties": {

            "title": {
                "properties": {
                    "en": {
                    ...
                    },
                    "zh_CN": {
                    ...
                    },
                    "zh_TW": { 
                    ...
                    }
                    ...
                }
            },

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to perform Common Terms on the `title.*` fields, but the following query does not return any results or error message.

```
"common" : {
    "title.*" : {
        "query" : "sleep",
        "cutoff_frequency" : 0.001
    }
}
```

However, if I change the above `"title.*"` to `"title.en"`, then I am able to get returned results.

How can I do the `"title.*"` search with Common Terms? Or can I?

Comment: How about using a `multi_match` with the `cutoff_frequency`like in your other question :-)

Comment: Val, I already got title.* working in multi_match. Because Common Terms is new to me, I would like to learn more about it, which is why I would like to know whether Common Terms works on title.* situation and how. Again, thanks for helping!

Comment: Common terms only works on a single field.

Comment: Val, thanks for your input. If you make it the answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a common terms query, just know that it only works on a single field, i.e. not several and not wildcarded ones.

Otherwise, you can use a `multi_match` query with the `cutoff_frequency` like in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101464/how-to-convert-filtered-query-with-multi-match-to-filtered-query-with-common-ter).

Answer (score 0):

is this working ? i use it to search a wildcarded (with*) value on many field

```
   {
    "query" : {
        "dis_max" : {
            "tie_breaker" : 0,
            "boost" : 1,
            "queries" : [
               {"wildcard" : {"title.en" : "sic*"}}, 
               { "wildcard" : { "title.zh_CN"  : "sic*"}},
               { "wildcard" : { "title.zh_TW" : "*sic*" }}
            ]
        }
    }
   }
```

dis_max les you run multiple queries and concat the result

Comment: Alainlb, thanks for chiming in. I am looking for wildcard (*) use in Common Terms. I hope to avoiding listing each language the way you did.